On the definition of an admissible representation of a $p$-adic group
Let $G$ be a reductive over a $p$-adic field $F$ and $(\pi,V)$ a (complex) smooth representation of $G(F)$. I know that the notion of admissible is defined as follows:

for any compact open subgroup $K<G(F)$, the space $V^K$ of $K$-fixed vectors is finite dimensional.

This is equivalent to:

there exists some compact open $K<G(F)$, such that as a representation of $K$, each $K$-isotypic part in $V$ has finite multiplicity.

I have a natural question: it seems that

"there exists some compact open $K<G(F)$ with $\dim  V^K<\infty$"

is not sufficient for admissiblity. Is this the case? If so, can we construct an example?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Edit: as pointed out by Broussou, you can pick an irreducible ramified representation of $G(F)$ and take direct sum for infinitely many times. Then for a hyperspecial maximal compact $K$, $V^K=0$, so after taking direct sum it is still $0$.
If I refine the question as: is

"there exists some compact open $K<G(F)$ with $0<\dim  V^K<\infty$"

sufficient for admissibility? Then using the same method, I can first take infinitely many copies of Steinberg then add one trivial representation.

What have you tried?

The post becomes confusing if someone answers your question, then you change the question (I am guilty of having done this too).  It depends on the situation, but in general I'd say it might be better to upvote and accept the answer, then ask a new question.

To find an example you have to  concider a non-irreducible representation.  Indeed by a theorem of Hervé Jacquet all irreducible (smooth) representations of a reductive G are admissible.
Take $G={\rm GL}(2,F)$ and $K={\rm GL}(2,{\mathcal O})$, where $\mathcal 0$ is the ring of integers of $F$. Let $V$ be the Steinberg representation. It is irreducible, admissible and $V^K =0$. Now let $W=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb Z} V_i$, where for all $i$, $V_i = V$. Then of course $W$ is not admissible, but $W^K =0$ is finite dimensional.

Oh thanks! You are right! If $\pi$ is irreducible and not unramified, I can take direct sum for infinitely many times. But can you give an example in which case $0<\dim (V^K)<\infty$?

Ok, that is a stupid question. You can just add one more trivial direct summand. Thanks!
